# Graphing calculator outputs different answer than what I've calculated myself using the correct methods.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have to find the formula for two points on a log-log plot: P1(0.90, 1.15), P2(46.20, 4.93).

I used the following methods to find both a and b in $f(x)=b\cdot x^a$:

$$
a=\frac{\log(y_2)-\log(y_1)}{\log(x_2)-\log(x_1)} = \frac{\log(4.93)-\log(1.15)}{\log(46.20)-\log(0.90)}= 0.37
$$

$$
b= \frac{y_1}{x_1^a}=\frac{1.15}{0.90^{0.37}} \approx 1.20
$$

$$
b= \frac{y_2}{x_2^a}=\frac{4.93}{46.20^{0.37}} \approx 1.20
$$

Although, according to GeoGebra b is supposed to be $0.18$. (Yes, I know GeoGebra doesn't have log-log plots, so I took the logarithm of both x and y values and then made a double variable analysis with linear regression, which gave me $y=0.3696 x +0.1787 \approx 0.37x+0.18$.

What have I done wrong?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since GeoGebra **doesn't know it's a log-log plot**, it just finds the formula for the straight line going through the given points (in log-log format).

So GeoGebra tells you that, using approximated result values:

$$\log y = 0.37\log x + 0.18, $$

which becomes

$$y = e^{0.37\log x + 0.18} = e^{0.18}e^{\log x \times 0.37} = e^{0.18}\left( e^{\log x}\right)^{0.37} = e^{0.18}x^{0.37} = 1.20x^{0.37}.$$

So, using 2 decimal places, your and GeoGebra's answer agree.

Basically what happened is that you transformed the problem into one GeoGebra could understand (well done!), but then you failed to transform GeoGebra's answer back to your original problem (it happens, look out for such things next time).